# Weird behaviour of LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN / 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941

Tags: active-directory

we have a weird behaviour we cannot explain.

We have a query like this

> (memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=Backup Operators,CN=Builtin,DC=test,DC=env)

To get all members of a group. E.g. we configured the Backup Operators group (Test env) to have the following members:

[image]

The query will only find Authenticated users and Leea. This is, for some reason the behaviour every time. All Foreign Security Principals except the "Authenticated Users" one are never picked up by the query and we can't figure out why.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching your domain for users where the `memberOf` attribute contains that group, or a group nested inside of that group.

The problem is that those objects do not have their `memberOf` attribute populated. If you open those accounts in AD Users and Computers, you'll that the Member Of tab is blank.

I can't really say why, since `Authenticated Users` looks like the same type of object, but it does have the `memberOf` attribute populated.

In general, `memberOf` can be spotty. For various reasons, you won't always find every member of a group by searching `memberOf`. To get every member of a group, you need to look at the `member` attribute of the group itself.

Comment: Thanks, the idea is definitly right. The attribute is only set in the Authenticated Users group. However in the "Member Of"-tab in the gui is correctly filled. I wonder on what basis so that we can form a good and reliable query.

Comment: Which account are you referring to when you say the "Member Of" tab in the gui is correctly filled?

Comment: Every single one. Current state is that AD features some kind of backlinks, you can also activate them in the attribute tab and then see the members of-attribute. However, based on the behaviour of the query I wildly guess that the backlinks are just some trick to peek into those attributes which are based on a two directional relation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677270(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: So the overall answer seems to be correct, the filter doesn't match because of the "missing" memberOf. I'll have to do some more research and then maybe a new, more defined question will arise ;)